# How to embed .xml file in .rc file?

Tags: xml, rc

I don't know how to embed xml file to rc file.

I already have a .xml file and I want to embed it to my .rc file. Can guys show me how to do that?
I searched the internet, asked chatgpt, and watched youtube but couldn't find my answer.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know how now. Just add: 1 24 "file_name.xml" in resource script file and it should work okay.